# check multiple guard in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, guard

I create three types of guards in laravel, I can check auth users but we have some route and controller that is same for all users and I need to check all guards in the same routes or controllers for each type of users that log in.

my auth.php file looks like this

```
<?php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],
        'finance' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'finances',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'finance-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'finances',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\student::class,
        ],
        'finances' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Finance::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\users::class,
        ],
        'finance' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\users::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'students' => [
            'provider' => 'students',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'finances' => [
            'provider' => 'finances',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
        'finance' => [
            'provider' => 'finance',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],
];
```

How I can check multiple guards in the same controller or route?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For each controller that you want to authentication

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin,student,finance');
    }
```

OR 
you can use in the route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin,finance,student'], function () {
    any same route here
});
```

And you can access to users details in blade like this

```
{{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name }} {{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->last_name }}
```

I Hope this helps some one.

Comment: `{{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name }}{{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->last_name }}` 
this will raise an error if the logged user was authenticated using different guard.
You can save the guard used to authenticate the user in the session  and use it to check again `{{ Auth::guard(Session('guard'))->user()->name }}`

Comment: Can't we simply use Auth::user()->name?