# How to redirect user to different page based on the guard for multi user system?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

In laravel 5.7 there is "Authenticate.php" file that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
 protected function redirectTo($request)
 {
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
  }
}
```

I have set admin guard for the admin user type (auth.php):

```
        */

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

How can i get the guard type from $request, so that I can check if the $guard name is "admin" set a different redirect page. Most tutorials are not covering 5.7 version yet.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I had your issue, you can follow this question and answer, I hope to help you.

> [How to check multiple gaurd in same laravel controller OR route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49871765/9246297)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49871781/9246297

Comment: Maybe just flag the question with the duplicate instead of pasting a link as an answer?